# Is there any way to use match method in template

Tags: angular

Is there any way to use method match in template. I mean :
Here is a part of template where I need to use match function:

```
 <span class="local-text">Text Length: {{textArea.value.length}} (without spaces: {{textArea.value.match(/\S/g).length}})</span>
        </p>
        <textarea ref-textarea #textArea [(ngModel)]="str" rows="10"></textarea>
```

I need to show text length without spaces. 
Is there a way to do it in the template?

Comment: I don't think so, it will be better to create a pipe and use that, why are you trying to achieve it in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a pipe, you can do it something like below to achieve the results

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'removedspaceslength',
    pure: false
})
export class RemoveSpacesPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(text: string): number {
        if (!text)
            return 0;
        return text.replace(/ /g, "").length;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
<span class="local-text">Text Length: {{text.length}} (without spaces: {{text | removedspaceslength}})</span>
<textarea ref-textarea [(ngModel)]="text" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Why is it return 0 when transorm returns boolean?

Comment: I have updated it to return the number. I copied it from my code and forgot to update the return type ;)